# How do I create a scratch file in IntelliJ 14?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, intellij-14, scratch-file

Scratch files are mentioned in the release announcement for IntelliJ 14 but it does not mention how to create or use them. Any links to documentation would be extremely helpful.

**What I Have Already Tried**

I have already performed several web searches for creating scratch files and the only things that have turned up are articles talking about the feature, none of which specify how to actually use the feature.

I have also tried "File"->"New...", but there is no option for scratch files.

I did find some documentation on scratch files in a [PhpStorm plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4428?pr=phpStorm), but, despite both being JetbBrains products, that appears to be completely unrelated and none of those shortcuts work.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you are going to downvote then give me feedback on why this question is being downvoted.

Comment: Did you check the help? [A comment from the announcement post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/intellij-idea-14-eap-138-2210-brings-scratch-files-and-better-mercurial-integration/#comment-272310) references hotkeys in the help.

Comment: Agree, no need to downvote this. If the answer is so obvious, why not ask in a comment if OP tried it and if/why it didn't work... +1 back to zero from me.

Comment: I would downvote this for a lack of research. I've never even heard of IntelliJ, but literally two minutes of searching found [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/scratches.html). Just by looking at the online documentation.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan What did you search to find that? All I was able to find was links to release summary.

Comment: I searched for IntelliJ and found their product page on JetBrains' web site. Then I just clicked on Support, found a link to their online documentation, and found it there. Maybe I'm old-fashioned, but I actually navigate around web sites without using search :).

Comment: I found the scratch file without help, but I don't know how to run it. Anyone has a example scratch file and how to run/execute it?

Comment: @KatedralPillon I believe that running scratch files is not yet supported... but it might have been added. Either way, this would be better off as a question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Tip: you can find any action in the menu "Help" -> "Find Action...".

This specific action is in the menu "Tools" -> "New Scratch File...".

Comment: Thanks for the "Find Action..." tip. You answer would have been even more helpful if you had mentioned keyboard shortcut to that find action: Control + Shift + A

Comment: so how do you run them, the scratch files I mean?

Answer (score 10):

Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately I am using a Mac and that short cut does not work.

Answer (score 9):

In Mac the shortcut is: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

Key map Mac OSX 10.5 : <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: It's actually Shift Control N

Comment: How do I run the java scratch?

Comment: @mahemadhi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120806/how-do-i-run-the-code-from-a-scratch-file-in-intellij-14