# How do I run the code from a scratch file in IntelliJ 14?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, intellij-14, scratch-file

I've created a simple Java scratch file containing a class named "*TestGenerics*" containing some code and a *main* method. 
**The code seems to be fine, however when I try to run it (by right clicking > Run 'TestGenerics.main()', I get this error: *"Module not specified"***

Similar situation occurs with a scratch file containing Lua code, error message: '*Error running scratch.1  (2): Executable is not specified*'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was previously not possible, but is now supported for some languages. such as [Java](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129961) and [Ruby](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16343). For these languages, you should be able to run the scratch file in the same way as you run any other file.

Comment: I see, that's a very limited feature given the code can't be executed (yet).

Comment: Since the bug tickets are closed, is it now possible to run the Scratch files?

Comment: I get an error for Java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457087/error-running-scratch-file-in-intellij-15