# Error running scratch file in IntelliJ 15

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

Code:

[image]

I get the following when running it:

[image]

Reference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmeDNZ-86ig

Settings (did not change anything here):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a solution see record "Eugene Zhuravlev 18 Feb 2016, 16:29" here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140228?replyTo=27-1304218

Seems like under mac IDEA's custom SDK home points to "IntelliJ IDEA 15.app/Contents" instead of "IntelliJ IDEA 15.app/Contents/Home".
As a workaround please define a project JDK in Project Structure | Project Settings | Project